# manner or simultaneously?

Tags: sentence-structure

There is such a statement in the book below. it mentioned that it is simultaneous. but can't we also think of it as "manner"? I understand this sentence in this way at the same time. Because it answers the question ''how'' . What is the difference?

*Source : A University Course in English Grammar
an action (main clause) and a mental process (-ing clause) occurring
simultaneously:*

They drove on, wondering how long their petrol would last. (additive = and wondered)

They drove on and wondered how long their petrol would last.

*And the statement in another book is this: Source : Compact Advanced Student's Book
description of the subject of the main clause; the
participle clause normally comes second:*

The volunteers arrived at the clinic feeling a little nervous.

This sentence also answers the question "how". Also this sentence is a ''manner'' sentence.

Comment: How do you drive in a manner where you're wondering how long your petrol will last? Does it affect your driving? Are you talking about driving in a way where you're trying to save fuel? Even then you'd probably not express it as a manner but as a cause for driving slowly or driving onwards looking for fuel.

Comment: If ''ing'' affects it, it is a simultaneous action, if not, it is ''manner''. that's the comment I wanted. Thank you for showing me this.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the verb.  In the first you have "wondering".  This is an action that they are taking.  It tells you what they were *doing*.

But the second is a verb that that describes an internal state. If you "feel" something, this verb is not something that you *do*, but something that you *are*.

As a main clause, the distinction remains:

> I feel nervous (feel is a linking verb, nervous is a complement)

> I wonder {what it is}  (Not a linking verb)